# How to sort two arrays according to one array's values

Tags: java

```
public static void getSort(short[] time, String[] champs){
    System.out.println("Time     Champs\n");
    for(int a= 0; a < time.length; a++){
        char Fletter=champs[a].charAt(0);
        if('B' == Fletter){
            Arrays.sort(champs);
            System.out.println(time[a] + "     " + champs[a]);
        }
    }
    for(int a= 0; a < time.length; a++){
        char Fletter=champs[a].charAt(0);
        if('C' == Fletter){
            Arrays.sort(champs);
            System.out.println(time[a] + "     " + champs[a]);
        }
    }
}
```

Hi guys, I'm in need for some advice and help on this function. What I am trying to do is output and display what is inside the arrays time and champs.

What my desire output is to have is:

```
Time----Champs

2001 Banana   

2004 Banana

2000 Boat

2003 Boat

2011 Carrot

2013 Carrot

2002 Cucumber
```

Where the time and champs are displayed correctly being displayed alphabetically
But when I use `Arrays.sort(champs);`

My output is:

```
Time----Champs

2004  Banana

2005  Banana

2006  Boat

2007  Boat

2008  Carrot

2009  Carrot

2010  Cucumber
```

The output of champs is displayed correctly but the years are listed down going down by 1.

And without the `Arrays.sort(champs)` my output is:

```
Time----Champs

2000 Boat

2001 Banana  

2003 Boat

2004 Banana

2002 Cucumber

2011 Carrot

2013 Carrot
```

Which as you can see the time is correct with the champs but not sorted alphabetically.

Comment: Why do you have `if('B' == first)` and `if('C' == first)`? And exactly the same loop? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your code scares me. And I would guess that it does exactly what you tell it to do. You're missing the concept of sorting arrays. Merge the time and champs into a tuple, then sort the tuple according to champs value.

Comment: what does first refer to?

Comment: Why do you have two loops that do exactly the same thing?

Comment: #MarounMaroun Sorry that was a typo. Basically what I am trying to do is display what is in the arrays only by what the first letter is, so that I can display it alphabetically #Dariusz For this homework I cant change the arrays, arrays are to be replaced with different values. #prashant it was a typo, it was actually meant to be Fletter. #Patashu I am trying to sorta out the arrays Alphabetically if I were to put the two if statements under one for loop it would not produce the output I would want its would most likely output something starting with B and then C and then back to B and so on.

Answer (score 2):

I think your issue is that you're not re-ordering the 'time' with the 'champs'.
From your example, it appears as though 'time' is just years in increasing order, and champs is whoever the champion team was for that year.
When you sort the Champs into alphabetical order, they're out of sync with the time.

To solve this, you need to pair Time with Champs so that if you sort by one of the values, the other moves with it.

Start with an internal class like this:

```
public static class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple>{
    public short time;
    public String champ;

    public Tuple(short time, String champ) {
        this.time = time;
        this.champ = champ;
    }

    public int compareTo(Tuple other) {
        return this.champ.compareTo(other.champ);
    }
}
```

Then, where change your current method to make an array of Tuples:

```
public static void getSort(short[] time, String[] champs){
   // assuming time.length & champ.length are the same
   Tuple[] timechamps = new Tuple[time.length];
   for (int a = 0; a < time.length; a++) {
     timechamps[a] = new Tuple(time[a], champs[a]);
   }
```

because we've made the new tuple implement Comparable, we can simply sort it. The compareTo method of the tuple sorts in alphabetical order properly.

```
   Arrays.sort(timechamps);
```

Then you can print out the results

```
   for (Tuple t : timechamps) {
     System.out.println(t.time+"\t"+t.champ);
   }
 }
```

Comment: Okay, I have no experiences with using tuples. How would I apply this to my code? From what I understand putting them together into a tuple will sync both arrays so that when it is displayed the output will be put correctly? Am I right? I m just a bit confused.

Comment: `timechamps[a] = new Tuple(time[a], champs[a]);` when I type that in I receive an error `no enclosing instance of type classname is accessible with an enclosing instance of type classname (e.g. x.new A() where x is an instance of classname)` and I can no longer compile

Comment: Whoops. You will need to chance Tuple to be a static class, or define it in its own file, or make getSort not static.

Answer (score 1):

Would you like to have a look here 
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-sort-a-map-in-java/

Here Key -----> champs
     Values --> time

I think you want to short your champs and time should be maintained with corresponding values.
Hope its helpful to you.

Comment: This would be a great way to do it. But that would mean having to take the value of the arrays and putting into a Map which I can't do. Because if the arrays values were to be replaced with something else, then this method wouldn't work. Thanks for contribution though :)

Comment: whta you mean by "Because if the arrays values were to be replaced with something else, then this method wouldn't work". Because I think it will work always. or else you are not clear whatever you want. The ans is pretty clear for the question you asked. give me a example, for which the above mentioned method won't work.

Comment: Because I would have to individually put the values of the arrays in to the map. Doing so in the event of having the arrays replaced with different values, lets say that instead of banana its batman. Then all the data in the maps would be invalid as it would have nothing to do with the arrays, right? You would have a sorted map of an output of Bananas when the arrays have the value Batman. I'm not a professional or anything that is just how I would see it. If I'm wrong please tell me. Cause it would help me improve upon my programming.

Comment: So obvious brother, If you change your input array, you have to recompute your output. Ok tell me, in your array logic(mentioned in you ques) if you change banana to batman, you have to recompute or not? I think yes.

Comment: There is always a way for every problem. First give it a try, then try to improve the code.

Comment: The thing is If i give my java file as is. To my marker, they will only replace the arrays and nothing else. At this point I can't change it to match their arrays.

Comment: You are not clear with your question. Please mention in proper way, mention some dummy value with input array, output array, then mention what is issue and how you tried to resolve it. that will help others to answer you up to the mark.

Answer (score 0):

It is better to create a Class and implement Comparable method

```
public class TimeChamp implements Comparable<TimeChamp>{

private short time;
private String champs;

public short getTime() {
    return time;
}

public void setTime(short time) {
    this.time = time;
}

public String getChamps() {
    return champs;
}

public void setChamps(String champs) {
    this.champs = champs;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(TimeChamp o) {
    if(getChamps().compareTo(o.getChamps())==0)
    {
        if(getTime()<o.getTime())
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;
    }
    else
        return getChamps().compareTo(o.getChamps());
}
}
```

Then you can create the function which will sort in your class like this

```
public void getSort(TimeChamp[] timeChamp)
{
    Arrays.sort(timeChamp);
    for(int i=0;i<timeChamp.length;i++)
    {   
        System.out.print(timeChamp[i].getTime());
        System.out.print("            ");
        System.out.println(timeChamp[i].getChamps());
    }
}
```

EDIT : Writing a more descriptive answer which constructs the data sets and calls the sort method

```
import java.util.Arrays;


public class MainExample {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
            //Construct data sets
    TimeChamp [] timeChampArray = new TimeChamp[3];
    TimeChamp timeChamp = new TimeChamp();
    timeChamp.setChamps("Boat");
    timeChamp.setTime((short)2001);
    timeChampArray[0]=timeChamp;
    timeChamp= new TimeChamp();
    timeChamp.setChamps("Banana");
    timeChamp.setTime((short)2000);
    timeChampArray[1]=timeChamp;
    timeChamp= new TimeChamp();
    timeChamp.setChamps("Banana");
    timeChamp.setTime((short)2001);
    timeChampArray[2]=timeChamp;
            //Call the sort method
    new MainExample().getSort(timeChampArray);
}
//the sorting method
public void getSort(TimeChamp[] timeChamp)
{
    Arrays.sort(timeChamp);
    for(int i=0;i<timeChamp.length;i++)
    {   
        System.out.print(timeChamp[i].getTime());
        System.out.print("            ");
        System.out.println(timeChamp[i].getChamps());
    }
}
```

}

Comment: how would I call getSort? would it be getSort(timeChamp);?

Comment: I get an error `Multiple markers at this line -The method getSort(classname, YearsWinners[]) in the type classname is not applicable for the arguements(short[], string[])` and the other is `-cannot resolve yearsWinners to a variable`

Comment: because of argument mismatch when you are calling the function

Comment: What would be the correct way of calling? or where would I have gone wrong with the arguements

Comment: check the latest edit in my answer..It contains the entire source code to run the program.

Answer (score 0):

I also had a go. This is a fully functional, self-contained solution.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class TimeAndChampSorter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // prepare input
        short[] time = { 2000, 2001, 2003, 2004, 2002, 2011, 2013 };
        String[] champs = { "Boat", "Banana", "Boat", "Banana", "Cucumber",
                "Carrot", "Carrot" };
        printSorted(time, champs);
    }

    public static void printSorted(short[] time, String[] champs) {
        // check arguments are of equal length
        if (time.length != champs.length) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                    "arrays time and champs must have equal length");
        }
        Tuple[] tuples = createTuples(time, champs);
        Arrays.sort(tuples);
        printTuples(tuples);
    }

    private static Tuple[] createTuples(short[] time, String[] champs) {
        // create empty array of Tuples with correct length
        Tuple[] tuples = new Tuple[champs.length];
        // fill the tuples array
        for (int i = 0; i < champs.length; i++) {
            tuples[i] = new Tuple(time[i], champs[i]);
        }
        return tuples;
    }

    private static void printTuples(Tuple[] tuples) {
        System.out.println("Time     Champs\n");
        for (Tuple tuple : tuples) {
            System.out.println(tuple);
        }
    }

    // static class to avoid having to create an instance of TimeAndChampSorter
    static class Tuple implements Comparable<Tuple> {
        short time;
        String champ;

        Tuple(short time, String champ) {
            // make sure champ is not null to avoid having to test for nulls in
            // compareTo
            if (champ == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("champ can not be null");
            }
            this.time = time;
            this.champ = champ;
        }

        // method of Comparable interface determines the ordering
        @Override
        public int compareTo(Tuple other) {
            return this.champ.compareTo(other.champ);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return time + "     " + champ;
        }
    }
}
```